# Minimum number of T gates needed to perform two overlapping Toffolis

Tags: circuit-construction

Consider this circuit:

[image]

How many T gates are needed to implement it, in the stabilizer+T gate set? The circuit can use cliffords, measurement, classical feedback, ancilla qubits, and T gates. Only T gates cost.

I know how to do it with 8 T gates, but don't know an easy way to show it can't be done with 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an intermediate result: **it takes at least 5 T gates**.

The T count of the overlapping Toffoli construction has to be exactly equal to the T count of two Toffolis that overlap at exactly one control, and those two Toffolis can be used to produce a state known to require 5 T states to produce.

This circuit with single-common-control Toffolis:

[image]

Is equivalent to this circuit with the overlapping Toffolis accompanied by various stabilizer operations:

[image]

I proved this using Quirk by [using one circuit to uncompute the other under the state channel duality.](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22QFT5%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputA5%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%2B%3DA5%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C1%2C%22X%22%2C%22X%22%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Measure%22%2C%22Measure%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A6%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputA5%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22-%3DA5%22%5D%2C%5B%22QFT%E2%80%A05%22%5D%5D%7D)

Also [I did the reverse direction](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22QFT3%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputA3%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%2B%3DA3%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%8A%96%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Measure%22%2C%22Measure%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A6%22%2C%22%E2%80%A6%22%2C%22%E2%80%A6%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputA3%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22-%3DA3%22%5D%2C%5B%22QFT%E2%80%A03%22%5D%5D%7D). Both operations can be used to perform the other, when stabilizer operations are free.

The single-overlapping-control circuit can be used to produce the state $|CCZ_{123,145}\rangle$ which, according to ["Lower bounds on the non-Clifford resources for quantum computations"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.01124), requires at least 5 T gates to produce. Therefore the T count is at least 5, but could be as high as 8.

[image]